# Trouble understanding how to send an array to a mySQL datatable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I just dove into using **phpmyAdmin** and **mySQL** today and I'm having some trouble understanding how to send an *array* to a table using a for loop. The `$tid` is a set number that changes transaction to transaction. `$wineFirstNames` and `$wineLastNames` are both arrays.

```
for( i=1;i <= $wineQty; i++) {
    $wineTastingTable = "INSERT INTO wineTastingTable (transactionID, wineFirstName, wineLastName) VALUES ('$tid','$wineFirstNames[$i]','$wineLastNames[$i]')"
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$wineTastingTable)) {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
       }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding `$` to the `i` variable in your first line of code?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF. That's with what summea suggested

Comment: You will probably also want to add a `;` at the end of the `"INSERT..."` line in your given code. _(As well as closing the for loop, as Adarsh notes...)_

Comment: That is because you have not closed the for-loop.

Comment: Moreover initiate the $i in the for-loop with a 0 (zero) instead of 1 because indexing in an array is done from 0.

Comment: Adarsh you are correct! I double checked and closed the for loop that was causing all sorts of problems, then I also set it to start at 0 since that's how the arrays work, and ended the variable with a semi colon. Gah, I think I just need to sleep/am trying to learn this stuff too late into the night. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i think you forgot adding `$` in for loop

```
    for( $i=1;$i <= $wineQty; $i++) {
                $wineTastingTable = "INSERT INTO wineTastingTable (transactionID, wineFirstName, wineLastName) VALUES ('".$tid."','".$wineFirstNames[$i]."','".$wineLastNames[$i]."')";
                if (!mysqli_query($con,$wineTastingTable)) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF 

It's saying the error is in the line with the if (!mysqli_etc...

Comment: ...and since the error mentions `T_IF`, the missing semicolon at the end of the query just before `if` is rather suspect.

Comment: tried it, the issue was the for loop wasn't closed and my version was missing the semi colon at the end of $wineTastingTable. Also needed to set $i=0 and then do $i <=($wineQty-1) (since wineQty starts at 1. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, all variables must be declared with `$` to be interpreted, otherwise (in your context) it'll be interpreted as a string.  You may always want to try a `foreach` loop, like so:

```
   foreach ($array as $item){
       $query="INSERT INTO wines (id, field1, field2) VALUES ($item[0], $item[1], $item[2])";
       MySQLi_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
   }
```

This is assuming a multi-dimensional array structure, but it looks like (from your post) that's what you're working with.